# Zend Framework 2 Doctrine2 leftJoin creating a separate SELECT query

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine-orm, doctrine, zend-framework2

Does anyone know why the Doctrine query below creates a separate join for the StandardDedescribed entity?

As you can see below this query pulls the information from the master entity 'EquipmentUK' and two related tables: 'SchemaInfo' and 'StandardDescribed'. It works well for the SchemaInfo, but creates another query for StandardDescribed. The relations in the Entities seem to be coded extactly the same, so I don't understand why it behaves differently for StandardDescribed?

```
$qb->select('e')
->from('\Lookup\Entity\Fullhistory\EquipmentUK', 'e')
->leftJoin(
    '\Lookup\Entity\Fullhistory\SchemaInfo',
    'si',
    Expr\Join::WITH,
    'e.schema_id = si.schema_id AND si.parent_schema_id != si.schema_id'
)
->leftJoin(
    '\Lookup\Entity\Intelligence\StandardDescribedUK',
    'sd',
    Expr\Join::WITH,
    'e.schema_id = sd.schema_id'
)
->where($qb->expr()->eq('e.vehicle_id', '?1'))
->setParameter(1, $jatoid);
```

Here are the Entities:

EquipmentUK:

```
namespace Lookup\Entity\Fullhistory;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * EquipmentUK
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="equipment",
 *  uniqueConstraints={
 *      @ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="search_idx", columns={"vehicle_id", "option_id", "record_id", "schema_id"})
 *  }
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class EquipmentUK
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $vehicle_id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $schema_id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $option_id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $record_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $location;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lookup\Entity\Fullhistory\SchemaInfo", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="schema_id", referencedColumnName="schema_id")     
     */
    private $schemaInfo;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Lookup\Entity\Intelligence\StandardDescribedUK", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="schema_id", referencedColumnName="schema_id")     
     */
    private $standardDescribed;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    private $data_value;

    public function getVehicleId()
    {
        return $this->vehicle_id;
    }

    public function getSchemaId()
    {
        return $this->schema_id;
    }

    public function getOptionId()
    {
        return $this->option_id;
    }

    public function getRecordId()
    {
        return $this->record_id;
    }

    public function getLocation()
    {
        return $this->location;
    }

    public function getSchemaInfo()
    {
        return $this->schemaInfo;
    }

    public function getStandardDescribed()
    {
        return $this->standardDescribed;
    }

    public function getDataValue()
    {
        return $this->data_value;
    }
}
```

SchemaInfo:

```
namespace Lookup\Entity\Fullhistory;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * SchemaInfo
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="schema_info")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class SchemaInfo
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="schema_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $schema_id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="parent_schema_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $parent_schema_id;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="location_schema_id", type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    private $locationSchemaId;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="scale_of_data", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $scaleOfData;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="data_type", type="smallint", nullable=true)
     */
    private $dataType;


    public function getSchemaId()
    {
        return $this->schema_id;
    }

    public function getParentSchemaId()
    {
        return $this->parent_schema_id;
    }
}
```

StandardDescribedUK

```
namespace Lookup\Entity\Intelligence;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * StandardDescribedUK
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="jato_uk_intelligence.standard_described")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class StandardDescribedUK
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $schema_id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="category", type="string", nullable=true)
     */
    private $category;

    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your joins should use Doctrine's own relational schema: your `EquipmentUK` has declared its relation with `SchemaInfo` via the property `$schemaInfo`, and it has also declared its relation with `StandardDescribedUK` via `$standardDescribed`. So:

```
$qb->select('e')
    ->from('\Lookup\Entity\Fullhistory\EquipmentUK', 'e')
    ->leftJoin(
        'e.schemaInfo',
        'si'
        //we don't need that third param as the relation is already known
    )
    ->leftJoin(
        'e.standardDescribed',
        'sd'
        //same here, no need for explicit relation
    )
    ->where($qb->expr()->eq('e.vehicle_id', ':vehicle'))
    //this here is a restriction, should be in WHERE instead of ON
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->neq('si.parent_schema_id', 'si.schema_id'))
    ->setParameter('vehicle', $jatoid);
```

Hope this helps!